# Nested If Exist statements in Batch File

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Ok, I'm trying to do a couple nested IF EXIST statements to check for the presense of a couple folders. If the first folder exists, set Folder1 to equal 1, and then skip to Install. Same with the Folder2, and then if neither folder exists just skip to install.

But even when Folder1 doesn't exist, this still sets %Folder1% to equal 1. What am I missing/not doing?

Thanks!

```
if exist "c:\folder1" set Folder1=1
    echo %Folder1%
    goto install
else if exist "c:\folder2" set Folder2=1
    echo %Folder2%
    goto Install
else goto Install   

:Install
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two fundamental problems:

A compound statement must be parenthesised.
Within parentheses, changing a variable value will NOT be visible UNLESS you have executed a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` - and even then you'd need to use !var! not %var%

So:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if exist "c:\folder1" (
        set Folder1=1
        echo !Folder1!
        goto install
) else if exist "c:\folder2" (
        set Folder2=1
        echo !Folder2!
        goto Install
) else goto Install 

:Install
```

Or preferably,

```
@ECHO off
if exist "c:\folder1" (
        set Folder1=1
        goto install
) else if exist "c:\folder2" (
        set Folder2=1
        goto Install
) else goto Install 

:Install

SET folder
```

Or even simpler

```
@ECHO off
if exist "c:\folder1" set Folder1=1&goto install
if exist "c:\folder2" set Folder2=1&goto Install
:Install

SET folder
```

---

Test:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
SET "folder1="
SET "folder2="
ECHO.----------No folders
DIR /b /ad c:\folder*
CALL :test
ECHO.----------Folder 1 only
MD c:\folder1
DIR /b /ad c:\folder*
CALL :test
ECHO.----------Folder 2 only
RD c:\folder1
MD c:\folder2
DIR /b /ad c:\folder*
CALL :test
ECHO.----------Both
MD c:\folder1
DIR /b /ad c:\folder*
CALL :test
RD c:\folder1
RD c:\folder2

GOTO :eof

:test
if exist "c:\folder1" set Folder1=1&goto install
if exist "c:\folder2" set Folder2=1&goto Install
:Install

SET folder
SET "folder1="
SET "folder2="
GOTO :eof
```

This test creates and deletes the two directories in question.

Here's the result:

```
----------No folders
----------Folder 1 only
folder1
Folder1=1
----------Folder 2 only
folder2
Folder2=1
----------Both
folder1
folder2
Folder1=1
```

Note that

```
    SET "folder1="
    SET "folder2="
```

Which is executed both at the start and after each report ensures that the environment variables in question are removed from the environment to prevent the code giving false results on stale information.

Comment: This commenting system sucks (Unless I don't know how to use this commenting system). Peter, I tried your simple solution, but it would always set Folder1 to equal 1, even if C:\Folder1 didn't exist.

Comment: In all probability, the variables were SET by a previous run. Variables have to be explicitly set to nothing to remove them from the environment. That's why most batch programs here have a `SETLOCAL` immediately after the `@echo off`. With `setlocal`, any environment changes are undone when the routine ends.

Comment: OK, I wasn't doing the SET "folder1=" to zero out prior, nor the SETLOCAL. So maybe I was using stale data. Let me try this again.

Comment: OK, this seems to work fine...and cleaner (although Endoro's worked too (thank you)). But do I need both SETLOCAL and SET "folderX=" commands? From what I gathered, they both do the same? Or is it best practice to have both in there?

Comment: There's no hard-and-fast rule. A `SETLOCAL` at the start of the program ensures that when the batch finishes, the environment is unchanged. It ***may*** be that the **entire point** of the program is to **SET** some environment variable(s). On the other hand, there's no guarantee that the variables you use within your program haven't **BEEN** set by some other means - from a previous run of a batch that **DIDN'T**  use `SETLOCAL` for instance, or simply from the user entering a `SET var=whatever` instruction from the prompt. The batch doesn't know, so the `set "var="` makes sure.

Comment: Gotcha...and that's what I thought you might have meant. Just a safety measure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist "c:\folder1" (
        set Folder1=1
        echo %Folder1%
        goto install
) if exist "c:\folder2" (
        set Folder2=1
        echo %Folder2%
        goto Install
) else goto Install 

:Install
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't set %folder1%=1 if folder1 doesn't exists, and it produces no output in this case. If Folder1 doesn't exists **AND** Folder2 exists **THEN** %folder2% is set to 1, otherwise %folder2% is empty. Put an unclosed left parentheses after the `echo`command to suppress the output, if a variable is empty.

```
@echo off &setlocal
if exist "c:\folder1" set "Folder1=1"
echo(%Folder1%
if not defined Folder1 if exist "c:\folder2" set "Folder2=1"
echo(%Folder2%
goto Install

:Install
endlocal
```

Comment: This solution seems to work, although more complicated/code. I'll have to test some more, but it looks like this will work for both Folder1 being present, folder2 being present, or neither being present.

Comment: This works like **else** and tests for folder2 only, if folder1 doesn't exists.